# Change the MBR without need to reinstall OS

Tags: ntfs, mbr

I have Windows XP installed on my computer and Ubuntu installed alongside Windows. MBR is on the Windows NTFS partition and I now want to delete the NTFS partition and use Ubuntu as my primary OS. Is it possible to do so? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have dual boot and starting through grub (or some other bootloader) you shouldn't have any problems with just formating the NTFS partition

[Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) may be useful for setting up the boot loader.